# JS file converting in JSP in spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

I want to convert spring application into angular js. I am using some external css and js.

css is included properly but not js.

when I use

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

It is considering angular.min.jsp and throwing error not found.

How to include external js into my app.

Comment: what you exactly want to do is totally not described please be specific to your Point what you asks

Comment: I am having one file called index.html inside web folder of spring application.
I have included some css and js here. 
when I run the application css are loading properly but not js the reason is spring is converting OR considering all js files as jsp 

for e.g <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

for above line it is showing like angular.min.jsp not found.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as some misconfiguration on the server side. 
I would suppose that you are using Apache 2.4 or Tomcat 7

In Apache 2.4 take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

If you were running the application in the ubuntu then default location to look at would be /etc/apache2 and usually this is going to be found in /etc/apache2/sites/available/000-default.conf

In Tomcat 7 take a look at
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Under Ubuntu with the default installation of Tomcat, this information will be found either in the file /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml or under the directory your application is deployed in META-INF/context.xml or under /var/lib/tomcat7/Catalina in one of the subdirectory. This depends a lot on the settings you have.

If neither of these is a case then take a look at the filters applied to the application as some of them can screw the answer. For them take a look at WEB-INF/web.xml or if you are using the XML-less configuration then try Some of the I believe SpringWebApplication classes.

If you still use the Spring to serve the backend then it is also possible that you have incorrectly set up ViewResolver, which returns .jsp as appendix instead of .js

Comment: My javascript Mapper is like this

<bean:bean id="javaScriptMapper"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <bean:property name="order" value="3" />
  <bean:property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
  <bean:property name="mappings">
   <bean:props>
    <bean:prop key="/**/*.js">JSPController</bean:prop>
   </bean:props>
  </bean:property>
 </bean:bean>

for any js file request it is looking into WEB-INF/View folder. In theory it doesnot exists at this location.

Comment: This one seems fine to me. The only thing that might be an issue is the order. It seems that there are other ViewResolvers configured before this one. Are you sure this one is actually used?